# Email notification via private message module

Tags: emails, privatemsg

I am using [private message](https://www.drupal.org/project/privatemsg) module to send an e-mail to all users. When I send mail, users can able to see the message in site only after logging in.

There is an email notification settings in private message module. What is the settings to send mail to user using private message?

Below screen shot shows the settings of email notification.[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: ... what about it?

Comment: @ NoSssweat - thanks for your response ...I am creting message it should send to user mail.i cant able to see any notifications in mail after creating new message it is displaying in user site only.

Comment: did u run cron... (-_-)

Comment: @ NoSssweat - yep it is running,But no result ,There is some other settings i will show you by screen shot of it.

Comment: @ No Sssweat - i have posted it.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your settings.

Comment: @No Sssweat - From the body of first screen shot,i want to change any thing.

Comment: Check video tutorial  http://codekarate.com/daily-dose-of-drupal/drupal-7-privatemsg-module-part-2-filters-roles-limits-emails

Comment: @ No Sssweat - I  have removed total message from body now it is sending mail.But when i am creating message "To" I have specified their user name to send mail,instead of that i want to give "ROLE OF USERS" it is possible to send mail by  using user role ?

Comment: I don't understand, where do you want to use the user role?

Comment: @ NoSssweat - I have posted in above pic in place  "To"  i want to specify my user roles ...in under one role i have 10 users i want sent a mail for all of that users.

Comment: @ No Sssweat - I can able to send message by using user role,but at that time mail nofication cant able to send for a role users

Comment: @ No Sssweat - hi are you there?I have an issue can you pls look that one...Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

## Part 1:

The answer to the question "**What is the settings to send mail to user using private message?**" is like so: these settings can be used to finetune the eMail to the user who received a "Private message", whereas such eMails are like a "notification" that there is a new Private message waiting on the site (and for which that user must head over to the site to actually read/see the private message).

Compare it so the various eMails a newly registered user may receive after a registration request got approved, which also requires such new user to go visit the site to actually start using the user id (to set a new password, etc).

## Part 2:

Below is a suggestion to address the 2nd part of your question, which you wrote in these 2 comments:

- **But when i am creating message "To" I have specified their user name to send mail,instead of that i want to give "ROLE OF USERS" it is possible to send mail by using user role ?** ...
- **I have posted in above pic in place "To" i want to specify my user roles ...in under one role i have 10 users i want sent a mail for all of that users.**

The [Privatemsg Bulkmail](https://www.drupal.org/project/privatemsg_bulkmail) module (for D6) would possibly address your question ... Provided "sending a private message" (instead of "sending an eMail") would be OK for your case. *If that's not what you want, then you should not be using the Private message module (that's not what it is for)*. The rest of my answer below assumes that "sending a private message" would be OK.

There are [currently no plans](https://www.drupal.org/node/1363952#comment-5337342) for a D7 version of that module. However, I'd use the [integration of the Privatemsg module with Rules](https://www.drupal.org/node/740366) instead (make sure to checkout this community docu, and its child pages ...), together with the [VBO](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations) module.

For more details, refer to the video about [Using Rules components with VBO](http://drupal.placeto.be/tutorial/using-rules-components-with-vbo). Possibly you also want to look at the 2 prior videos and/or the 2 subsequent videos (all about [Views Bulk Operations](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations)), i.e.:

- [Introducing Views Bulk Operations](http://drupal.placeto.be/tutorial/introducing-views-bulk-operations).
- [More details about VBO settings](http://drupal.placeto.be/tutorial/more-details-about-vbo-settings).
- [Using Rules componens with more than one parameter](http://drupal.placeto.be/tutorial/using-rules-componens-with-more-than-one-parameter).
- [Using VBO to load list of objects into Rules](http://drupal.placeto.be/tutorial/using-vbo-to-load-list-of-objects-into-rules).

In this specific case;

- use [Views bulk operations](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations) to create the list of your users to be targeted (in this case a list of users that corresponds to your **ROLE OF USERS**).
- use [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) action "Send a message" (provided by Privatemsg module).

PS: yet another great usage of the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module, in this case in combination with the [Privatemsg](https://www.drupal.org/project/privatemsg) module.

Comment: @ Pierre Vriens - Thanks for your response,I want to send by using private message module email notification when selected role,I tried regarding to your suggestion my requirement is not matched with that ..is it possible to send bulk mails with private messages based on role?..

Comment: The only solution that I am aware of to do this, is as I described in my answer above. And as I already wrote in my answer: if that's not what you want, then you should not be using the Private message module (that's not what it is for).